# Rewrite regexp in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

This is the nginx config:

```
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/threads/ /thread.php?$uri&$args last;
}
```

That code works fine, but I want to use another route now.

```
OLD: /threads/123-yyy-yyy-yyy
NEW: /xxx-xxx-xxx/123-yyy-yyy-yyy
```

I've tried some like:

```
rewrite ^\/[\w]+\/([\d]+-[\w]+)?$ /thread.php?$1&$args last;
rewrite ^/[\w]+/([\d]+-[\w]+)?$ /thread.php?$1&$args last;
rewrite ^/\w+/(\d+-\w+)?$ /thread.php?$1&$args last;
rewrite ^/\w+/(\d+-\w+)$ /thread.php?$1&$args last;
```

But the page is not found, so I guess there is something wrong in my regex.
Might it be $uri/$1 parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to add `&$args` to your rewrite rules. As nginx `rewrite` documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite),

> If a *replacement* string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended, for example:
>
> ```
> rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;
> ```

2. `\w` metacharacter includes `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and underscore(`_`). It doesn't include dash character. You can try this regex:

   ```
   rewrite ^\/[-\w]+\/([\d]+-[-\w]+)$ /thread.php?$1 last;
   ```